# Making polygon transparent using javafx canvas

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am working with canvas in javafx. On canvas I have a hexagon which needs to be redrawn. I am using images with alpha, so I cann't just draw image atop and remove what was before.
I tried to use GraphicsContext.clearRect, it clears rectangle, and I want to clear hexagon. How can I do it?